# ng-grid search filter with cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, filtering, ng-grid, celltemplate

I have a problem using ng-grid search filter on column wich references cellTemplate.

My data object has multiple fields. One of those fields is an array and I use cellTemplate to create a div with ng-repeat to show those values and apply a certain css class according values from that array.

Here is the plunkler that demonstrate my problem: plnkr.co/edit/jMvafIjqCsU0cnW6Ecvy?p=preview.

My problem is when I use cellTemplate grid propertie, the filter do not work properly. To simulate this scenario, you can try search by person2@gmail.com that you'll notice the problem. In this plunker, I use a cellTemplate to concatenate '@gmail.com' to person's email so if you type person2 the filter is applied, but after type @ you'll see that filter do not work.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

ng-grid does not search on the rendered `cellTemplate` output but on the underlying data.

So the best way would be to transform your data to have searchable values.

```
  angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(value) {
    value.email+='@gmail.com';
  });
```

Find a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ARlDisOS0EVHXKjQPast?p=preview)

Comment: And if i want apply a css style? For example, if the email is @gmail the output will be green, else the output will be red? This is my real problem, when I should use cellTemplate to manipulate the output because I cant neither apply a style from my controller or to show an array of values on cell.

Comment: How do you detect if an email is @gmail or anywhere else? Didn't find any hoster info in your plunker example, just the names. Please complete myData in the plunker and I will show you how to write your cellTemplate.

Comment: You´re right. I edited your plunker to show what is my problem and I want try doing. Please, see the plunker.

Comment: Hello, you're still with me? Look at the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ARlDisOS0EVHXKjQPast?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, we are now in plunker version hell. What plunker did you update?

Comment: You can't update my plunker because it's frozen. You can only fork it and you have to tell me the new adress.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken. Here it is: http://plnkr.co/edit/GrA7VqaXRFvP2BUTrq8l?p=preview

Comment: Could someone help me please?

Comment: Can't reach http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ from my workplace right now. Will look into your plunker later.

Comment: Ok. I've looking for a solution but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Oh, github.io is online again! Look here at this (very hackerish) plunker. Enter values like 200 or 100 in the searchbox. Again, this is a transformation of your json to a searchable value which is the data field of the column. The celltemplate decides which class to use on the actual meassurements data. Not very stylish, but hey, it works! http://plnkr.co/edit/Iuw025179PRBzottQzet?p=preview